# Placing image next to text with Text-overflow: ellipsis using bootstrap on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use `text-overflow: ellipsis`with bootstrap's class `text-nowrap`and place image next to this text. So text on the left and image on the right on the same line. I tried the following, but didn't work. I want text and image on the same line, with `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="text-nowrap " style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; ">
        <a>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing</a>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 30px;">
    </div>   

</div>
```

And here is the code http://www.bootply.com/P0lbiPhLDo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add to the first div:

```
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:55%;
```

while for the second div:

```
display:block;
position:relative;
width:40%;
```

The snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-lg-6">

  <div class="text-nowrap" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;position:relative;display:inline-block;width:55%;">
      <a>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing</a>
    </div>

  <div style="float:right;display:block;position:relative;width:40%;">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 30px;">
    </div>   

</div>
```